# How to use vendor bundles resources in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, assetic

I know this is a very basic question and I'm pretty puzzled that I couldn't find a good answer for that.

Let's say I installed twbs/bootstrap package with Composer, so it lands in its proper vendor/twbs/bootstrap/ directory. Now, what do I need to do to make it actually useful, i.e. copy the bootstrap/dist/ folder containing css/js files to the web/ folder?

Is there any (semi)intelligent 'Symfonic' way to handle this or should I a) copy/update the needed files manually, b) setup e.g. a grunt copy task for that?

I'm using Symfony 2.6 on Windows 7 if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only install repositories that are **symfony2** bundles. In case of https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap, it isn't.

You'll have to find another bundle for symfony2 doing the same, like this one for instance: https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle

And as explained [in their doc](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html) like almost if every bundle doc, here is how you install this bundle (the procedure is the same for the majority of them):

> **Installation**
>
> BraincraftedBootstrapBundle should be installed using Composer:
>
> ```
> {
>     "require": {
>         "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "~2.0"
>     }
> }
> ```

*part about Bootstrap and jQuery sniped, not directly relevant to hoiw install a bundle, go read it in the doc.*

> Then add the bundle to your AppKernel.php:
>
> ```
> # app/AppKernel.php
>
> class AppKernel extends Kernel
> {
>     public function registerBundles()
>     {
>         $bundles = array(
>             // ...
>             new Braincrafted\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\BraincraftedBootstrapBundle(),
>         );
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> BraincraftedBootstrapBundle highly recommends you to use Assetic for
>   managing assets. If you do use Assetic for managing your assets, you
>   should now run the dump command.
>
> ```
> php app/console assetic:dump
> ```

Comment: I dind't take a look to what he have installed but this is a good answer to me

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. I even saw the braincrafted/bs website but tried to avoid the middlemen. So if I need to use something which is not repackaged for symfony, I'm basically on my own with how I add it to the project no matter if I use Composer, Bower, npm, etc.?

Comment: In summary yes, you'll have to integrate it yourself. But then you can make a package of it, easily reusable in your other projects, and then even publish it to github for everyone benefit :)

Answer (score 2):

for posterity :
just added in my assetic config under config.yaml:

```
assetic:
  assets:
    bootstrap_css:
        inputs:
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        filters:
            - cssrewrite
        output: bundles/twbs/bootstrap.css
```

just added after in my base.html.twig template, anywhere in the header :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/twbs/bootstrap.css') }}" media="screen" />
```

Do the trick,don't know if it's 'state of the art', but it work.
thanks to http://www.tutodidacte.com/symfony2-installer-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

As always, the official docs hold the answer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html

Comment: How does that help when it's not a Symfony 2 bundle?

Comment: Well, you should obviously favor Symfony bundles.  From what I can see, the bundle in question is simply just Bootstrap with no PHP, so you're likely better off just downloading from Bootstrap directly, then installing the proper files in `src/path/to/bundle/Resources/public/css|js`.  For PHP bundles, Composer follows the autoloading PSRs (either 0 or 4, depending on what you prefer).  You then just include the compiled autoloader file that Composer creates (https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading).  Again, the docs for the various technologies (Symfony, Composer) are where to go.

Comment: Symfony automatically includes the `vendor/autoload.php` file for you.